# Merging data in multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, rows

I am a newbie to oracle queries.

I am making an excel file which gets data from an oracle database.

Kindly help me in achieving this task.

For eg; I have 2 tables. 1st table contains columns as roll num and name.(roll num is unique)

2nd table contains columns as roll num ,subject and mark.(ie,for each subject there will be a row for each roll num)

I need to combine the results as a excel file containing columns roll num,name,subject 1 mark,subject 2 mark,subject 3 mark.

How can i achieve it? Kindly guide me how to query

Answer (score 0):

```
  select a.rollnum num,a.name name,
  max(case when b.subj='science' then b.mark end) "ENG Marks",
  max(case when b.subj='maths' then b.mark end) "Maths Marks",
  max(case when b.subj='computer' then b.mark end) "Computer Marks" 
  from first a inner join second b 
  on a.rollnum=b.rollnum
  group by a.rollnum,a.name 
  order by a.rollnum;
```

- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40d45/15

Comment: This query will yield many rows for a single person . I need like 1,XYZ,20,40,60 (ie,roll num ,name,english mark,maths mark ,computer mark). Single row for each roll num

Comment: Ans modified. Try to provide the Sample o/p when posting your requirement.

Comment: hope modified ans suits to your requirement.. if yes Please accept the ans

Comment: My pleasure.. If it satifies your requirement upvote and accept ans